# What is better way to storage configuration variables (for example states of program) in program?

Tags: c++, global-variables

- to make them as global variables or to storage them in some class?
  I'm not sure that implementing of singleton in this case is proper solution.

Comment: More details and some code about your problem may help.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. "configuration variables" sound like something that should be in an external file like "settings.ini" which is initially read by a Singleton or similar, but "example states of program" sounds like phases that should be done as `enum`. Like the other guy already said, give some details and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a **Singleton** that handles all the configuration